# Let individual digits multiply each other until reaching single digit using basic methods Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
  function multiply(arr)
  {var finalcount=0; var k=1;
   for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
   {     k*=arr[i]



        finalcount++;}

  return finalcount
  }



  document.write(multiply([2,3,4,5]))
</script>
```

My main problem is that the initialization of k=1 is conflicting with if (k>=10).(the condition I am trying to set since I am trying to reach a single digit at the end and count how many times the loop has to run to reach that. Now I don't know where to put the if statement.

For example, the input is [2,3,4,5], then I want 2*3*4*5=120, then 1*2*0=0, 0 is a single digit, and it took two loops so the finalcount will be 2, that's the result I want.

Any advice is appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: use reduce() function  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce]

Comment: @Mamun I want to count how many times the digits have to multiply each other to reach a single digit.

Comment: *"I want to count how many times the digits have to multiply each other to reach a single digit."*... well, this is far from clear.

Comment: I'm still not certain what you want in the result.  2*3*4*5 would be 120.  Is that the result you want?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado write a function that takes an array of digits and returns the number of times I must multiply the digits in num so as to reach a single digit.

Comment: @JonDeWitt No, I want the 120 to continue multiply each other, 1*2*0=0, that's a single digit, which is the result I am trying to reach.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado no lol I was copying the assignment's instruction in the hope that it would make it clearer. Sorry if that offends you. English is not my first language.

Comment: @JiangYuxin Thanks, no worries, I had a hint that this would be the assignment. Next time wrap it in `*`, which will make it italics, *like this*, or use quotes (`"`). Well, back to the assignment: I believe your teacher should had explained it better, it's clear as mud the way it is right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. you are trying to multiply digits of a number and continue doing this until you reach a single digit.
if I am right I have this solution for your question

```
//this function Convert the number to array htere are other solurions as well.
function numberToArray (num){
    var tmpString = num.toString();
    var tempArray= []; 
    for(var i=0; i<tmpString.length;i++){
        tempArray.push(Number(tmpString[i]));
    }
    return tempArray;
}
function multi (arr){
    var count = 0;
    var k=1;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        k *=arr[i];
    }
    count++;
    if (k<=10) return count;
    else{
        var newArray = numberToArray(k);
        return count +multi(newArray);
    }
}

console.log (multi ([2,3,9,7,6]));// returns 4: 23976->2268->192->18->->8
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Hi, is there a possible way to combine these two functions?

Comment: what do you mean? do you want to combine numberToArray and multi?

Comment: Yes :) So that I only have to enter a number and have the final count.

Answer (score 0):

combining the two function is rather easy. you can include the other function inside the multi function:

```js
    function multi (num){
     var tmpString = num.toString();
        var tempArray= []; 
        for(var i=0; i<tmpString.length;i++){
            tempArray.push(Number(tmpString[i]));
        } 
        var count = 0;
        var k=1;
        for (var i=0; i<tempArray.length;i++){
            k *=tempArray[i];
        }
        count++;
        if (k<=10) return count;
        else{
            return count +multi(k);
        }
    }
    console.log (multi (23976));// returns 4: 23976->2268->192->18->->8
```